# Android Sqlite - Updating a table for a string

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a simple question : 
I'm new to sql so i have this question :

The below method works if names is a number. How to write this query if names is a string?

```
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv , KEY_NAME + "=" + names, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals in SQL are quoted in `'single quotes'`.

Though it's preferable to use `?` literal placeholders and bind arguments here, e.g.

```
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{names} );
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but it gave me an error ! Invalid syntax expression on "?"

Comment: @user3496326, you should change `KEY_NAME + "=" + ?` to `KEY_NAME + "=?"`

Comment: Yes there was a missing terminating `"` - added by @Ȃŵåiṩĸîŋg edit.

Comment: @laalto Thanks a lot mate :) been searching this simple thing for an hour :)

Comment: Thanks to @laalto for adding this answer
and good to hear that is working